# UICollectionView - Mutiple & single selection in different sections by Swift4

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to do the multiple selections in UICollectionView, and I have five section that has different selection setting.
I want the single selection in section 1 and 2.
And multiple selections in section 0, 3 and 4.
When I click the same item twice, it will deselect that item.
However, when I click the single section items, it'll cancel previously selected item and select clicked item.

I follow the other answer that I achieve this in UITableView successfully, but I don't know how to do this in UICollectionView perfectly?
Thanks.

```
var collectionView: UICollectionView!
var selectArray: [IndexPath] = []

func collectionViewSetting(){
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
    self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
}


func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    let count = 5
    return count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let key = Array(conditionsDictionary.keys)[indexPath.section]
    let array: [String] = conditionsDictionary[key]!

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.label.text = "12345"

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
    selectArray.append(indexPath)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    if let index = selectArray.index(of:indexPath) {
        selectArray.remove(at: index)
    }
}

print(selectArray)
```

Answer (score 3):

As per your requirement i have prepared a sample code which is working properly.

**Swift 4**

```
    //
    //  ViewController.swift
    //  SOCollectionSelectionHandling
    //
    //  Created by Test User on 05/02/18.
    //  Copyright © 2018. Ltd. All rights reserved.
    //

    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        var collectionView: UICollectionView!
        var selectArray : [IndexPath] = []
        let sections  = 5
        let cell = "MyCell"

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            setUpCollectionViewAndSettings()
        }

        func setUpCollectionViewAndSettings() {

            let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
            layout.itemSize = CGSize.init(width: 50, height:  50)
            collectionView = UICollectionView.init(frame: self.view.frame , collectionViewLayout: layout)
            collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cell)
            collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
            collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            collectionView.delegate = self
            collectionView.dataSource = self
            collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true

            self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
        }
    }

    //MARK: Collection View Delegate and DataSource Methods

    extension ViewController : UICollectionViewDelegate , UICollectionViewDataSource {

        //MARK: Collection Data  Source
        func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
            return sections
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 10
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: self.cell, for: indexPath)
            if selectArray.count > 0 {
                selectArray.forEach { (selectedIndex) in
                    if (selectedIndex.section == indexPath.section && selectedIndex.row ==  indexPath.row) { // Change Color of selected Index
                        if (selectedIndex.section == 0 || selectedIndex.section == 3 || selectedIndex.section == 4) {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: selectedIndex)
                                cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
                            }
                        } else {
                            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
                        }
                    }
                    else { //Set Default Color of Not Selected Index
                        if indexPath.section == 0 || indexPath.section == 3 || indexPath.section == 4 {
                            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
                        } else {
                            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if indexPath.section == 0 || indexPath.section == 3 || indexPath.section == 4 {
                    collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
                    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
                } else {
                    collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
                    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                }
            }
            return cell
        }

        //MARK: Collection Delegate for Selection and Deselection

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
            if indexPath.section == 0 || indexPath.section == 3 || indexPath.section == 4 {
                self.handleMultipleSelection (collectionView: collectionView ,cell : cell! , indexPath : indexPath )
            } else {
                selectArray.removeAll()
                collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
                cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
                selectArray.append(indexPath)
                print(selectArray)
                collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }



        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)

            if indexPath.section == 0 || indexPath.section == 3 || indexPath.section == 4 {
                self.handleMultipleDeSelection(collectionView: collectionView
                    , cell: cell!, indexPath: indexPath)
            } else {
                //Remove all selected record from array for Single Selection
                selectArray.removeAll()
                cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            }
            collectionView.reloadData()
        }


        //MARK: Multiple Selection Handle Method

        func handleMultipleDeSelection(collectionView: UICollectionView
            , cell: UICollectionViewCell, indexPath: IndexPath) {
            // Remove Previous Selected Cell Record from Array at time of Section Switching
            if selectArray.count > 0 {
                selectArray.forEach({ (path) in
                    if (path.section == indexPath.section) {
                        if let index = selectArray.index(of : path) {
                            let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: path)
                            if path.section == 0 || path.section == 3 || path.section == 4 {
                                cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
                            } else {
                                cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                            }
                            selectArray.remove(at:index)
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
            if let index = selectArray.index(of:indexPath) {
                selectArray.remove(at: index)
                print(selectArray)
            }
            else {
                //Removing Unwanted Section from array
                if selectArray.count > 0 {
                    selectArray.forEach({ (path) in
                        if (path.section == 1 || path.section == 2) {
                            if let index = selectArray.index(of: path) {
                                let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: path)
                                cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                                selectArray.remove(at:index)
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
                //Adding Selected cell in Selection Array
                selectArray.append(indexPath)
                print(selectArray)
                collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }


        func handleMultipleSelection (collectionView: UICollectionView ,cell : UICollectionViewCell , indexPath : IndexPath )  {
            // Remove Previous Selected Cell Record from Array at time of Section Switching
            if selectArray.count > 0 {
                selectArray.forEach({ (path) in
                    if (path.section != indexPath.section) {
                        if let index = selectArray.index(of : path) {
                            let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: path)
                            if path.section == 0 || path.section == 3 || path.section == 4 {
                                cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
                            } else {
                                cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                            }
                            selectArray.remove(at:index)
                        }
                    }
                })

            }

            collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange

            if let index = selectArray.index(of:indexPath) {
                selectArray.remove(at: index)
                print(selectArray)
                collectionView.reloadData()
            } else {
                //Removing Unwanted Section from array
                if selectArray.count > 0 {
                    selectArray.forEach({ (path) in
                        if (path.section == 1 || path.section == 2) {
                            if let index = selectArray.index(of: path) {
                                let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: path)
                                cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                                selectArray.remove(at:index)
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }

                //Adding Selected cell in Selection Array
                selectArray.append(indexPath)
                print(selectArray)
                collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Hey @tolerate＿Me_Thx Did you find my answer helpful?